# Need help on Rails app - Query is executed but data on view is not shown

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have started learning Ruby on Rails and I have been stuck at something and need you help. To learn Rails, I am building an app for creating, filling and reporting surveys.

My model is like - Each Survey has many Questions and each Survey has many Responses. Each Response has many Answers.

On my reports page controller, I am doing something like -

```
def index
    #@survey = Survey.find(params[:survey_id])
    @user_responses = Response.where("survey_id = ?", params[:survey_id])
end
```

and on the view -

```
<% @user_responses.each do |response| %>
 Responder Name - <%= response.responder_name %><br/>
 <% response.answers do |answer|%>
Question Id - <%= answerx.question_id %>
Answer - <%= answer.answer_text %>
<%  end%>
<% end %>
```

I can see the query being executed on the backend (due to the loop on the view), e.g.

```
[1m[36mResponse Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "responses".* FROM "responses" WHERE (survey_id = '14')[0m
[1m[35mAnswer Load (0.3ms)[0m  SELECT "answers".* FROM "answers" WHERE ("answers".response_id = 14)
[1m[36mAnswer Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "answers".* FROM "answers" WHERE ("answers".response_id = 15)
```

But on the view I am not able to see the "answer_text"/"question_id". I can only see "responder_name"

This has something to do with queries being executed from the view ?

Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
<% response.answers.each do |answer| %>
```

With an `each`.